# How can i reset the total rows of my table on the same button click at each time?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

i am using UITableView with the following delegates.

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource=self;

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

 {

    return 1;

}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return 5;enter code here
}
```

it will set the number of Rows in a section at the loading time.

it will trigger the following delegate and i can do whatever i need with table cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
```

However i need to create/reset the table rows dynamically(on a button click) and need to trigger

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

this delegate to set some datas to table cell.

how can i call this delegate in a button click.and also i need to reset the total rows of my table on the same button click at each time.

can any one help me to do it.

Comment: ca i reset the total rows of my table on the same button click at each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

And they all lived happily ever after.

Comment: how can i reset the total rows of my table on the same button click at each time

Comment: When you call `reloadData`, your `numberOfRowsInSection` method will be called again. Just make sure it returns the new correct value when called, and the number of rows will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the dataSource of your table view and then call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

so in a button action you should:

```
-(void)buttonClicked{
     tableViewArray = ...//load array with new data;
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: how can i reset the total rows of my table on the same button click at each time.

Answer (score 0):

Have to set:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      
{ 
    **return [tableViewArray count];**
}

- (void)buttonClicked
{
    tableViewArray = ... //load array with new data;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```